# How to get values back from multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

```py
class Return_Thread_Value(object):
    def __init__(self,target = None,args = (),**kwargs):
        self._que = queue.Queue()
        self._t = Thread(target = lambda q,arg1,kwargs1: q.put(target(*arg1,**kwargs1)),
                         args=(self._que,args,kwargs), )
        self._t.start()

    def Return_Value(self):
        self._t.join()
        return self._que.get()

Thread_1 = Return_Thread_Value(target = Walking_Inputs,args = (
    WINDOW,CLOCK,Hero,FRAME,INTERACTING,TOP_SCREEN,POSITION_DATA,BACKGROUND,
    FOREGROUND_OPAQUE,FOREGROUND_TRANSLUCENT,INPUT,INPUT_SHIFT,PROMPT_SHIFT,Input,
    ENTERED))

INTERACTING,TOP_SCREEN,Input,ENTERED = Thread_1.Return_Value()

Thread_2 = Return_Thread_Value(target = Key_Inputs,args = (
    WINDOW,ENTERED,PROMPT_SHIFT,INPUT,INPUT_SHIFT,CAPITAL,Input))

ENTERED,PROMPT_SHIFT,INPUT,INPUT_SHIFT,CAPITAL,Input = Thread_2.Return_Value()
```

Trying to run two functions, one that lets you walk about the village and another that accepts key inputs, both functions are running, but I'm not sure if the values are being returned.

Comment: Both functions accept key inputs, with w,a,s and d being crossovers

Comment: Why is it can't you tell if the values are being returned?

Answer (score 1):

They threads will each have their own scopes, to pass data back to their parent thread, the easiest way is to define any object for example a dict `return_value = {}` and pass that as an arg to your thread.

Set the value you want to return as a key in the dict (
`return_value['thread1return']='something'`), and you should be able to access it in the parent thread